# My code is no dry, how to extend in function?

Tags: angularjs

```
function forgot(email) {
    $scope.myPromise = Auth.forgot({'email': email}).then(function (response) {
        if (response.data.validator || response.data.errors) {
            return;
        }

        $('#modalConfirmation').modal('show');
    });
}

function confirmation(token) {
    Auth.confirmation({'token': token.trim()}).then(function (response) {
        if (response.data.validator || response.data.errors) {
            return;
        }

        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + response.data.token;
        $('#modalConfirmation').modal('hide');
        $('#modalReset').modal('show');
    });
}

function reset(password) {
    Auth.reset({'password': password}).then(function (response) {
        if (response.data.validator || response.data.errors) {
            return;
        }

        $location.path('/login');
    });
}
```

Looks that if is repeat on each .then. Any way to make it better?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could throw an error from within a middleware:

```
function checkForFailure(response) {
    if (response.data.validator || response.data.errors) {
            throw new Error('Validation failed, or error occurred');
    }
}


function forgot(email) {
    $scope.myPromise = Auth.forgot({'email': email})
        .then(checkForFailure)
        .then(function (response) {
            $('#modalConfirmation').modal('show');
        });
}

function confirmation(token) {
    Auth.confirmation({'token': token.trim()})
        .then(checkForFailure)
        .then(function (response) {

            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + response.data.token;
            $('#modalConfirmation').modal('hide');
            $('#modalReset').modal('show');
        });
}

function reset(password) {
    Auth.reset({'password': password})
        .then(checkForFailure)
        .then(function (response) {
            $location.path('/login');
        });
}
```

Of course you could add an extra level of abstraction by creating a sort of proxy when using an `Auth` method which would always bind a then with the middleware `checkForFailure`, but that may be overkill.

Comment: all my factory method, need to checkForFailure, can we to do this on interceptor?

Answer (score 0):

```
// New Function
function getAuthAction(actionName, parameterObject, callback){
    return Auth[actionName].call(Auth, parameterObject).then(function (response) {
        if (response.data.validator || response.data.errors) return;

        callback(response);
    });
}

// Usage
function forgot(email) {
    $scope.myPromise = getAuthAction('forgot', {'email': email}, function (response) {
        $('#modalConfirmation').modal('show');
    });
}

function confirmation(token) {
    getAuthAction('confirmation', {'token': token.trim()}, function (response) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + response.data.token;
        $('#modalConfirmation').modal('hide');
        $('#modalReset').modal('show');
    });
}

function reset(password) {
    getAuthAction('reset', {'password': password}, function (response) {
        $location.path('/login');
    });
}
```